Как сгруппировать значения по меткам в запросе Prometheus?
У меня есть метрика sync_unit_type{region="krg"} 731441289. Значение - дата и время, представленное в секундах (Unix time). Есть различные регионы, и значения обновляются постоянно каждые 5-7 минут. В UI Grafana мне нужно сгруппировать записи по регионам и выбрать максимальное значение для каждого региона, что будет представлять последнее время, когда произошло событие. Также нужно отобразить это в виде таблицы, которая будет иметь два столбца: название региона и дата/время в формате dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss. В данный момент я пытаюсь достичь этого с помощью запроса PromQL, который совсем не работает. Я уже настроил переменную $Region в дашборде графаны, чтобы фильтровать значения по конкретному региону.
Мой запрос: max by (region) (sync_unit_type{job="main (prod)", region=~"$Region"} * 1000) умножаю на 1000, так как Grafana ожидает значение в миллисекундах.
